# Why is ngx-translate loading the whole http response?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular-httpclient

For some reason, my Angular 5 project seems to be pulling the whole http response into the translationService. Has anyone experienced this? Is this a HttpClient issue?

As you can see in the attached image, the json content is in the `_body` property, and that is not correct. For me, it seems like HttpClient is used with `{observe: 'response'}` under the hood somewhere. [ref.](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

[image]

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(["en", "nb"]);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }
}
```

Versions:

```
@angular/core@5.1.3
@ngx-translate/core@9.0.2
@ngx-translate/http-loader@2.0.1
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, what do you mean pull the entire request?

Comment: It can't request only part of the JSON file

Comment: Look at the image. The json content is in the _body property, and that is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, but it was able to resolve it. First you must to equalize version corresponding to your Angular version. then you move you code to base bottom after
export class AppModule{}. this is the code that you have to move:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}
```